# What data structure do I use here?

Tags: c#, data-structures

I have lots of instances two classes `Children` and `Animal` which have a **many-to-many** entity relationship.

I want to have a data structure such that given a `Children` I can get a list of `Animal` that are mapped to it and vice versa. For any given `Animal` I can get a list of `Children` that are mapped to it.

I need this data structure to be concurrent such that it can be accessed by any thread.

So given an example mapping:

```
Child1 -> Animal1
Child1 -> Animal2
Child1 -> Animal3
Child2 -> Animal2
Child2 -> Animal3
Child3 -> Animal3
```

Querying for `Child1` I wish to get a returned list: `[ Animal1, Animal2, Animal2 ]`.

Querying for`Animal2` I wish to get a returned list: `[ Child2, Child3 ]`.

The only way I could think to do this was using a dictionary and a list for each item in this dictionary (both Animals and Children) but I would then also have to deal with locking an synchronization of the lists which is troublesome.

Comment: You should really add a mapping table, such as AnimalChildren to help remove that many to many.

Comment: Using plural nouns for a class name is bad style; consider renaming your class to "Child".

Comment: Can this many-to-many relationship change over time, or once you have a set of children and animals, their relations are fixed? It is a lot easier to make an operation threadsafe if there are no writes.

Comment: @EricLippert yes the relationship can change.

Comment: OK, imagine that you have a graph data structure. Nodes are children and animals, and the relation is edges between them. Does the code doing the querying have a reference to just a node, or a node *and the whole graph* that the node is in? What I'm getting at is: is there some "database" object that you're querying, or do you have to have all the information *in each individual object*?

Comment: The querying will be done from an omniscient object. (I think that answers your question). At the moment I don't have any information stored anywhere as I haven't implemented it. I am happy for the objects themselves to have any information they want.

Comment: Then my approach would be to implement a threadsafe multi-value dictionary that maps from `object` to `IEnumerable<object>` as my implementation, and then wrap a facade around that which enforces the rule that a `Child` always maps to a sequence of `Animal` and vice versa.

Answer (score 7):

I think you have to split up your data structure into three tiers.

```
Child <- ChildToAnimalRelation -> Animal
```

So `Child` and `Animal` both have collections of `ChildToAnimalRelation`

```
public class ChildToAnimalRelation 
{
    public Child Child { get; set; }
    public Animal Animal { get; set; }
}
```

Getting an animals children would be done as follows:

```
var children = currentAnimal.ChildToAnimalRelations.Select(r => r.Child);
```

vice versa:

```
var animals = currentChild.ChildToAnimalRelations.Select(r => r.Animal);
```

Comment: Consider that by splitting in this way between different tiers, any type of update in your framework has to cary on updating every tier of interest.

Comment: The two lines getting the animals or children you put at the end of your answer will return *all* animals or children, not just the once for a given counterpart. You will have to add a where-clause beforehand...

Comment: @Spontifixus: the collection is on the counterpart *itself* and does not contain *all* relations. I edited the variable names to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a list and then use Linq for query? One possible implementation:

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> allItems=new ...
allItems.Add(Tuple.Create("Child1", "Animal1");
...
var child1RelatedItems=allItems.Where(entry =>entry.Item1=="Child1");
var animal1RelatedItems=allItems.Where(entry =>entry.Item2=="Animal1");
...
```

Comment: Whether this will suffice depends mostly on the input.  Its performance is directly related to how many relations there are (rather than how many children or animals).  If the mapping between the two is dense, and you have lots of both...oi.  If it's just a couple, this will do.

Comment: Probably not alone.  The ChildToAnimalRelation class is serving the same purpose as your tuples.  You don't gain anything but more descriptive names.  What the other answer is doing is attaching the relations to each child and animal, so it only has to loop over the ones that match that particular thing.